# Rails call specific js.rb manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I have this bit of code refreshing the event when I update it.

**event/update.js.erb**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', [<%= @event.id %>]);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
  'renderEvent',
  $.parseJSON("<%=j render(@event, format: :json).html_safe %>"),
  true
);
```

Lot of my events are related and I would like to be able to call this manually on every event every time as one of them is updated.

I'm trying to do something like this but I've no idea how to make the javascript call and it doesn't feel right either.

```
  def update        
    @event.update(event_params)

    Event.all.each do |event|
      # call event's javascript
    end

  end
```

Any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it every time, just do it in the view.

```
# controller
def update        
  @event.update(event_params)
  @events = Event.all
end

# update.js.erb
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', [<%= event.id %>]);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    'renderEvent',
    $.parseJSON("<%=j render(event, format: :json).html_safe %>"),
    true
  );
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think it could be that easy. Thanks a lot